# How to get AUD price of bitcoin at a particular date using GOOGLEFINANCE

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am trying to find out how to get the price of bitcoin, ethereum, litecoin and bitcoin cash in AUD at a particular date.

I have a table as follows

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Price |
+------------+-------+
| 16/03/2016 |       |
| 19/04/2016 |       |
| 03/12/2017 |       |
+------------+-------+
```

I have tried entering using:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BTCAUD", "price", A2)
```

However, I get the error:

```
When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'BTCAUD' returned no data.
```

Comment: [Works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbttU.png) in our end.

Answer (score 0):

Date format is incorrect, try as `03/16/2016` and in formula `=GOOGLEFINANCE("BTCUSD", "price",A2)`.